# Rails 4 carrierwave gem TypeError on assign to uploader

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I'm using the carrierwave gem to set up image upload on a nested form. The uploader looks like:

```
class CarImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

    include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

    if Rails.env.production?
        storage :fog
    else
        storage :file
    end

    def store_dir
        "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
    end

    def default_url
        'default-no-car-pic.png'
    end

    version :thumb do
        process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
    end

    def extension_white_list
        %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
    end

end
```

The model looks like:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user
    has_one :car_info, dependent: :destroy
    has_one :car_spec, dependent: :destroy
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :car_spec, :car_info

    mount_uploaders :car_images, CarImageUploader

    validates_associated :car_info, :car_spec, presence: true

end
```

The view form:

```
<%= form_for @car, html: { multipart: true, class: "form-horizontal" } do |f| %>

    <%= f.fields_for :car_spec do |car_spec_field| %>

        # Fields for car_spec

    <% end %>

    <%= f.fields_for :car_info do |car_info_field| %>

        # Fields for car_info

    <% end %>

    <%= f.label :images %>
    <%= f.file_field :images, multiple: true %>

    <%= f.submit "Add car" %>

<% end %>
```

The `create` action in `CarsController` looks like:

```
@car = current_user.cars.build(car_params)
@car.car_images = params[:car][:images]

respond_to do |format|
  if @car.save

    format.html { redirect_to @car, notice: 'Car was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @car }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @car.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

This code results in `TypeError in CarsController#create` `can't cast Array to` when I submit the form. The `car_images` field was added to the `cars` table as`json` field. According to the instructions on carrierwave github this is correct, but it is throwing the above error on form submit. What is causing this error and how can I correct the code so that the form will submit?

Comment: Did you find the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error.

> TypeError: can't cast Array to

As said in documentation  https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#multiple-file-uploads you need do migration

```
rails g migration add_avatars_to_users avatars:json
```

The problem is in type column *json*. SQLite3 and MySQL have not this type as it in PostgreSQL. You can migrate it as *text*

```
rails g migration add_avatars_to_users avatars:text
```

For me it's work.

Answer (score 1):

Same error with sqlite3:

Put this in your Model:

```
serialize :avatars, Array
```