# Array not displaying images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, sqlite, carrierwave

I need help coding an array that displays user loaded images. I searched forums and tutorials and I am ready to admit I'm stuck! I can see the files loading into the database but I cannot access them.

Thank you for your help.

I am using `rails 5` and `ruby 2.3.1p112`

```
gem 'carrierwave', github: 'carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave'
gem 'sqlite3'
```

I have:

```
class Micropost < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 200 }
  mount_uploaders :pictures, PictureUploader
end

class MicropostController < ApplicationController
.
.
  def create
    @micropost = current_user.microposts.build(micropost_params)
.
.
params.require(:micropost).permit(:content, {pictures: [ ]})
```

My form:

```
<%= f.file_field :pictures, multiple: true, accept: 'image/jpeg,image/gif,image/png' %>
```

My view:

```
<%= image_tag micropost.pictures_urls %>
```

My terminal response:

```
Started GET
"/images/[%22/app/assets/images/37/%5B%22Thankyou.jpg%22%5D%22]" for
::1 at 2016-08-03 18:11:08 -0700    Started GET
"/images/[%22/app/assets/images/33/%5B%22Thankyou.jpg%22%5D%22]" for
::1 at 2016-08-03 18:11:08 -0700 Started GET
"/images/[%22/app/assets/images/35/%5B%22detailsaboutus.jpg%22%5D%22]"
for ::1 at 2016-08-03 18:11:08 -0700 ActionController::RoutingError
(No route matches [GET]
"/images/[%22/app/assets/images/37/%5B%22Thankyou.jpg%22%5D%22]"):
Started GET
"/images/[%22/app/assets/images/36/%5B%22GPcolors4.jpg%22%5D%22]" for
::1 at 2016-08-03 18:11:08 -0700 Started GET
"/images/[%22/app/assets/images/34/%5B%22GP-digital-logoclear.gif%22%5D%22]"
for ::1 at 2016-08-03 18:11:08 -0700 . . . .
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32493672/6665229

Answer (score 1):

To solve this problem I updated the model:

```
class Micropost < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
  validates :user_id, presence: true
  validates :content, presence: true, length: { maximum: 200 }
  mount_uploaders :pictures, PictureUploader
  serialize :pictures, Array                 #updated code
end
```

In the view:

```
<% @micropost.pictures.each do |picture| %>
  <article> <!--used to stylize view -->
     <%= image_tag(picture.url) %>
  </article>
<% end %>
```

Also when I created the Micropost model for production in AWS S3 and psql db :pictures is type 'text':

```
rails g model Micropost pictures:text...
```

or 
    `rails g migration add_field_to_microposts pictures:text`

open the migration

```
add_column :microposts, :pictures, :text
```

[more info here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html)

then
   `rails db:migrate`

Hope this helps another rookie!

Answer (score 0):

This look like you upload file with has_many relation so you getting multiple images and its an array of image urls

you can do this

```
<% micropost.pictures_urls.each do |url| %>
<%= image_tag url %>
<%end%>
```

Comment: Jayesh -sorry for the late reply, I had to take a break. Thanks for the tip -the problem persists. b/c of you I discovered the image_tag is not pointing to the correct <img src=" ">.